# Kask Bambino Pro Evo

Tags: helmets, triathlon, time-trial

I am interested in testing Kask Bambino Pro Evo helmet for my next Triathlon race and I was wondering if someone had used this before and might wanna share some info on it. Maybe a comparison between Mitral, Beluga and this? Obviously, the fit is individual and on some might be faster/slower that the others.

Plus, I don’t seem to find this anywhere in Canada/US shops and the Kask website restrict access to the webpage saying it’s a geographical restrictions. Any ideas on how to buy one of these?

Comment: Per the FAQ, this isn’t the site for product recommendations. You may be better off asking on Slowtwitch.com.

Comment: Another possible site is https://sports.stackexchange.com/ but they also tend to class product-specific questions as Off Topic.  If you want this to stay open here, try rephrasing it as more "what features should I look for in a triathlon helmet"

Comment: I presume https://www.kask.com/en/cycling/helmets/bambino-pro_24_8.htm  ?  Works for me from an AWS address.  Try using a phone to view website.

Comment: @Criggie Bambino Pro Evo is a different helmet than bambino pro